# Extending Array's prototype not building in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

In my `TypeScript`-based application I want to add some functionality to the `Array`-prototype.

Therefore I added a file `Array.d.ts` to my project which contains:

```
interface Array<T> {
    selectMany<TOut>(selectListFn: (t: T) => TOut[]): TOut[];
}
```

Then I created another file under `/Scripts/Extentsions/Array.ts` where I've implemented the function:

```
Array.prototype.selectMany = Array.prototype.selectMany || function<TIn, TOut>(selectListFn: (t: TIn) => TOut[]): TOut[] {
    return this.reduce((out, inx) => {
        out.push(...selectListFn(inx));
        return out;
    }, new Array<TOut>());
}
```

In another file I'm going to use the "extension" on an `DivisionResource[]`-array where `DivisionResource` is just the concrete type of the array's elements.
Intellisense shows no errors but when running `webpack` it throws

> TS2339: Property 'selectMany' does not exist on type 'DivisionResource[]'.

I don't get the point what is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap merging for global types with "global", like this;

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        selectMany<TOut>(selectListFn: (t: T) => TOut[]): TOut[];
    }
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

---

You could also try adding a triple slash reference of declaration file to .ts file.

```
/// <reference path="../Array.d.ts" />
```

Comment: This throws `TS2669: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.`

Comment: You are right, I got that error too (with TS 2.6.2). Could you try adding a reference of definition file to .ts file?

/// <reference path="./Array.d.ts" />